# How to check in script if upstart event was emited?

Tags: networking, upstart, xdg, events

I am running remote connection on session start using xdg autostart script. But sometimes network interface needs more time to start. So I need to check if network is up.

Is it possible to check if an upstart event was emited (I.e. *net-device-up*)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: No.

Long version: Upstart events themselves are not recorded (unless --verbose or --debug used as init parameter and you grep `dmesg`). What you can do is check if a job whose `start on` stanza is `net-device-up` has been started (or make one for yourself for this purpose only).

Alternatively you can check `ifconfig` output in your remote connection script for a properly configured `eth0` (whatever if you're using).